# Trouble while trying to un-tar Django

Tags: django, macos, installation

I am new to Django and I am having trouble installing it. I am on a fairly updated Mac, and I already have Python 2.7.2. I downloaded the newest version of Django, which is 1.4. The Django website is telling me that i need to untar Django by running the command:

tar xzvf Django-1.4.tar.gz

However, terminal is just giving me back- tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open 'Django-1.4.tar.gz'

Why is this happening? I tried running the command python setup.py install and that's not working either.

Comment: are doing that command from the same directory as the downloaded tar.gz file?

Comment: @sarnold: I can confirm its a valid usage of tar on osx

Comment: @samold OS X 10.6.8 on my laptop has no problem with tar xzvf somefile.tar.gz  it just works.

Comment: @sdjuan: You are most likely correct about the OPs issue. I think they left off the trailing tell-tale error snippet: "No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0):

Just install django via pip (the package manager). Once you have pip, you can easily install packages from: http://pypi.python.org/pypi

**Install via pip**

```
$ pip install django
```

**Installing pip (if not already installed)**

```
easy_install pip
```

**If you don't yet have easy_install either**

Download this:
http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py

And do:

```
python ez_setup.py
easy_install pip
```

Comment: Okay I figured it out, I had to change directories to my downloads folder. Thanks sdjuan! Let's see how far I can actually get with Django if I couldn't even figure out that one!